# Does recvfrom() modify len?

Tags: c, linux, ip, packet

sendto() give me "invalid argument" because len decrease by 2 bytes from 20.
Why calling recvfrom() modifies len?

```
s=socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));    
struct sockaddr_ll sll;
len=sizeof(sll);
bzero((char *)&sll, sizeof(sll));
sll.sll_ifindex=3;

rf=recvfrom(s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sll, &len);

st=sendto(s, buf, 6+6+2+20+8+8, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sll, len);
```

Comment: Think...why you pass a pointer to actual `len` to the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [quote the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/recvfrom)

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>  ssize_t recvfrom(int socket, void *restrict buffer, size_t length,
>       int flags, struct sockaddr *restrict address, socklen_t *restrict address_len);
> ```

and,

> [...] If the `address` argument is not a null pointer and the protocol provides the source address of messages, the source address of the received message shall be stored in the sockaddr structure pointed to by the `address` argument, and the length of this address shall be stored in the object pointed to by the `address_len` argument.

So, it's status-by-design, `recvfrom()` will modify the value pointed by the last argument, provided

- the `address` argument is not a null pointer
- the protocol provides the source address of messages